# Error: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN

Tags: android

I can't figure out why my onClick method for my buttons are not working. Everytime I click the button, my logcat says ViewPostImeInputStage Action_Down.

I appreciate any help!

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        BluetoothConnect fragment = new BluetoothConnect();
        transaction.add(R.id.sample_content_fragment, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And this is my fragment.

public class BluetoothConnect extends Fragment {

```
//For debugging purposes
private static final String TAG = "BluetoothConnect";


// Intent request codes
private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE = 2;
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 3;

//Main buttons
private Button shareButton;
private Button listenButton;
private TextView test;

/**
 * Name of the connected device
 */
private String mConnectedDeviceName = null;

/**
 * Local Bluetooth adapter
 */
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    //Get local Bluetooth adapter
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();



    //If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        activity.finish();
    } 
}

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        listenButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.listen);
        shareButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.share);
        test = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.test);
    }


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //If BT is not on, request that it be enabled
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    } else {
        setupButtons();

    }
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //Figure out what to do if we need to destroy

}

@Override public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //figure out what to do if person pauses out of app

}

public void setupButtons() {
    Log.d(TAG, "setupButtons()");

    //Initialize the music buttons

    listenButton.setOnClickListener(new ButtonOnClickListener("listen"));

    Log.d(TAG, "finished listenButton");

    shareButton.setOnClickListener(new ButtonOnClickListener("share"));

}



private class ButtonOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    String type;

    public ButtonOnClickListener(String button) {
        Log.d(TAG, this.type);
        this.type = button; 
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (this.type == "listen") {
            listenMusic();
        } else {
            shareMusic();
        }
    }
}


private void ensureDiscoverable() {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() !=
            BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);
    }
}

private void listenMusic() {
    Log.d(TAG, "OMG ITS WORKING");
}

private void shareMusic() {
    Log.d(TAG, "OMG ITS WORKING");
}
```

}

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

have a look here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32016362/5281187

Wrap your layout over the one you already have