# ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN

Tags: android, button, android-fragments

As I'm trying to debug my program, I can't figure out the error.

I have initialized two buttons and used .setOnClickListener on them. 
When the user clicks the buttons, they are supposed to see a debug message
on LogCat. However, I keep seeing this message appear instead whenever I click the button, or if I click anywhere at all on the screen: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN.

Does anyone know what that message signifies, or if they a solution to my problem?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I am running into the same issue. All of a sudden nothing is clickable. It makes no sense. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I figured it out! Can you post your xml? I believe I can resolve this issue for you.

Comment: This bug now happens straight out of the box.  Simply start a new project, select empty Activity, run it, tap on the screen, and watch these error messages in Logcat.  And it seems that none of these solutions work, sigh.  (AS 3.4.2 using *any* base layout).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN is a bug that occurs stemming from the rare instance where your layout is rejected and you are no longer able to click on any clickable items, and what occurs instead is a ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN with every button press (and no action). The solution for this is simple, wrap your layout content with a parent. So if you xml format was

```
<LinearLayout <---root layout
...
<!-- your content -->
</LinearLayout> <-- root layout end
```

change to

```
<FrameLayout <---root layout
   <LinearLayout <-- parent wrap start
   ...
<!-- your content -->
   </LinearLayout> <-- parent wrap end
</FrameLayout> <-- root layout end
```

This solution should resolve that conflict. Atleast this is what has worked for me. Cheers!

Comment: My answer has helped a few people but it still has not been marked as the accepted answer. Mind accepting it? Thanks!

Comment: I also face this issue but I do get it with a GLSurfaceView so wrapping in xml's isn't possible

Comment: @portfoliobuilder tried your answer but still facing the same issue list click ends the activity and close the app without crashing only gives ViewRootImpl ACTION_DOWN warning.. now tired to solve this issue

Comment: I have grid as root layout and facing the same issue what should I do ? @portfoliobuilder

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem as yours,and I tried portfoliobuilder's way but it didn't work.
And then I just make some changes on my code,then it worked.
I just set every instance of my button an OnlickListener interface instead of  letting my Class inplements the View.OnClickListener~

```
button.setOnclickListener(new View.OnClickListener){
public void onClick(View v){//...
}
}
```

INSTEAD OF

```
public YourClass implements View.OnClickListener{...
public void OnClick(View v){
switch(v.getId()){
case://...
break;}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue which was corrected when I made the relative layout clickable(in properties).

cheers

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me on the first click of a CardView inside a RecyclerView.  It turns out the CardView XML set:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Once I removed that, the first click (and subsequent clicks) worked fine, and I no longer had the error with ACTION_DOWN.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting `ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN` message when a line of my code had -->

```
if(button.getText().equals("word"))
```

I got the desired output after correcting the if statement to -->

```
if(button.getText().toString().equals("word"))
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions above worked to me. Pretty strange bug, wondering if some view is intercepting the touch events and broking it, maybe some appcompat stuff, there is a lot of touch intercepts over there…

Anyway, I workarounded the problem adding a transparent `View` over my real broken button and adding the click listener on this view, pretty ugly but it worked `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

e.g. imagine the error happened in this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/broken_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="Hello world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I added the transparent view and I set the click on it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/broken_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="Hello world" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/workaround_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/broken_button"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/broken_button"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/broken_button"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/broken_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Again, it is an ugly solution, but still a solution.