# Android error: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer, onclicklistener

I created a navigation drawer in a base activity for my android app, much like many seen online. Though it seems as though my list view items when clicked (visually), though won't fire off when clicked, not even when trying to log when clicked.

This is the error I get when trying to click the item in the listview:

D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN.

I am have had many 'ideas' of what is wrong, such as the child activity is being placed over the base activity. I have looked online for an answer but can't seem to find one.

Edit: I found out that if creating another button in the drawerlayout, it will fire off. But the listview items still give the same error.

Any ideas?? Thank you!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30968660/23118