# onClick not doing anything... "ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN"

Tags: java, android, paypal

I'm working on an app that uses PayPal. I need to use the MPL, as opposed to the SDK, because my app needs to be able to implement third-party payments.  I've followed various tutorials and created the code below.  I don't get any compiler errors, and no log cat error, but when I run it and click on the "Pay with PayPal" button, nothing happens.  Instead, I get  `ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN` when I click on the button or anywhere on the screen.

I have no idea why.  Please help!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

private CheckoutButton launchPayPalButton;
final static public int PAYPAL_BUTTON_ID = 10001;
private double _theSubtotal;
private double _taxAmount;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    initLibrary();
    showPayPalButton();
}

private void showPayPalButton() {
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams linearLayoutParam = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    setContentView(linearLayout, linearLayoutParam);

    LayoutParams lpView = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    // Generate the PayPal checkout button and save it for later use
    PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();
    launchPayPalButton = pp.getCheckoutButton(this, PayPal.BUTTON_194x37, CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);

    // The OnClick listener for the checkout button
    launchPayPalButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Add the listener to the layout
    launchPayPalButton.setLayoutParams(lpView);
    launchPayPalButton.setId(PAYPAL_BUTTON_ID);
    linearLayout.addView(launchPayPalButton);

   }

public void PayPalButtonClick(View arg0) {
    PayPalPayment newPayment = new PayPalPayment();
    newPayment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal(_theSubtotal));
    newPayment.setCurrencyType("USD");
    newPayment.setRecipient("my@email.com");
    newPayment.setMerchantName("My Company");
    Intent paypalIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(newPayment, this);
    this.startActivityForResult(paypalIntent, 2);

}



public void initLibrary() {
    PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();

    if (pp == null) {  // Test to see if the library is already initialized

        // This main initialization call takes your Context, AppID, and target server
        pp = PayPal.initWithAppID(this, "APP-80W284485P519543T", PayPal.ENV_NONE);

        // Required settings:

        // Set the language for the library
        pp.setLanguage("en_US");

        // Some Optional settings:

        // Sets who pays any transaction fees. Possible values are:
        // FEEPAYER_SENDER, FEEPAYER_PRIMARYRECEIVER, FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER, and FEEPAYER_SECONDARYONLY
        pp.setFeesPayer(PayPal.FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER);

        // true = transaction requires shipping
        pp.setShippingEnabled(false);


    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0){

    PayPalButtonClick(arg0);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you haven't set the content view after super.oncreate() and since you're registering your activity as the on click listener, its responding to clicks from anywhere on the screen instead of just the button.

EDIT

Add an on click listener to the button like this

```
paypalButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {  PayPalButtonClick(arg0); }
});
```

and remove the implementation of the OnClickListener from your activity

Comment: Thanks...  I'm having problems because I've never set views programmatically; only used .xml files.  Should I use 'setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);'?  How do I resolve the onClickListener problem?

Comment: It looks like you're not building your view from an xml so doing setContentView(linearLayout) at the end of your showPaypalButton() should work.

Comment: I changed it to: 

`launchPayPalButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                payPalButtonClick(arg0);
            }
        });`

But the problem remains.  Also, I did set the contentView in the showPaypalButton method.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN` is basically a condition when  your layout is rejected and you are no longer be able to click on any clickable items.The solution for this is simple, just wrap your layout contents with a parent.

for ex:

```
if you have the xml with format as:
<LinearLayout <---root layout
 ..... contents here
</LinearLayout> <-- root layout end

change to 

<FrameLayout <---root layout
   <LinearLayout <-- parent wrap start
   ...
<!-- your content -->
   </LinearLayout> <-- parent wrap end
</FrameLayout> <-- root layout end
```

for more information, you might wana consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30968660/viewpostimeinputstage-action-down)

Comment: Thanks but I'm creating the layout programmatically, so I'm not using .xml files.

Comment: I don't think I can since I'm using the button code from the PayPal MPL.

Comment: if thats the case, may be you should  build this hierarchy from the code and give it a try i mean with the framelayout  as a parent!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  Also, I really don't understand the reason for this error.  I've read your response and the link you posted, but nothing I can find explains why this is happening.

Comment: I switched my code so that I inflate a layout from an xml file, and added the button programmatically to that layout.  On the xml file, I wrapped the layout in a parent layout, but the problem remains.  Any help?