# Log message I don't understand: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN

Tags: java, android, xml, paypal, onclicklistener

I'm trying to create an app that uses PayPal.  In order to figure out the PayPal aspects, I'm trying to create a simple app that shows a "buy with PayPal" button, that then starts the library that should take the user through the PayPal login and payment process.  When I start the app, it works and a "buy with PayPal" button shows properly at the bottom of the screen, but when you click on it, nothing happens.  I get no logcat errors, but the message I get is:

> 03-13 21:24:30.157 28062-28062/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN

That's the first line of the logcat output when the button is pressed, which is followed by:

> 03-13 21:24:30.237 28062-28062/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo time:37196632
>   03-13 21:24:30.317 28062-28062/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/Activity: performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
>   03-13 21:24:30.317 28062-28062/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/Activity: performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
>   03-13 21:24:30.347 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/MPL: start CHECK_AUTH
>   03-13 21:24:30.347 28062-28062/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@235ce6d4 time:37196744
>   03-13 21:24:30.347 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/MPL: start makeDeviceInterrogationRequest Post
>   03-13 21:24:30.347 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/Server API: Endpoint https://mobileclient.sandbox.paypal.com/GMAdapter/DeviceInterrogation
>   03-13 21:24:30.347 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/Server API: Header: CLIENT-AUTH = No cert
>   03-13 21:24:30.347 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/Server API: Header: X-PAYPAL-MESSAGE-PROTOCOL = SOAP11
>   03-13 21:24:30.347 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/Server API: Header: X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID = APP-80W284485P519543T
>   03-13 21:24:30.347 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/Server API: Header: X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-SOURCE = 1.5.6
>   03-13 21:24:30.347 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/Server API: Header: X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT = XML
>   03-13 21:24:30.347 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/Server API: Header: X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT = XML
>   03-13 21:24:30.347 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/Server API: Header: x-paypal-service-version = 1.0.0
>   03-13 21:24:30.347 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/Server API: Header: x-paypal-element-ordering-preserve = false
>   03-13 21:24:30.347 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/Server API: Request - 2.0APP-80W284485P519543T1.5.6UG7TYVDJ6QYUA00PZX633HXLUGKN11UXTN47329YL8S01KXDFMAEAVAULY10hltetmoIMEI357518057171597hltetmoSM-N900TAndroid21Phonefalseorg.kevinbright.android.paypaldemoorg.kevinbright.android.paypaldemoPayPalDemoAndroidGSM1.5.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
>   03-13 21:24:30.347 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/NetworkHandler: postXML do execute
>   03-13 21:24:31.097 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/Server API: Resonse Header: Date = Mon, 14 Mar 2016 01:24:30 GMT
>   03-13 21:24:31.097 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/Server API: Resonse Header: Server = Apache-Coyote/1.1
>   03-13 21:24:31.097 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/Server API: Resonse Header: X-EBAY-SOA-REQUEST-ID = 15372b97-6020-a487-1905-fe9dfff47095!GMAdapter!10.72.113.144![]
>   03-13 21:24:31.097 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/Server API: Resonse Header: X-PAYPAL-SERVICE-VERSION = 1.0.0
>   03-13 21:24:31.097 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/Server API: Resonse Header: X-PAYPAL-SERVICE-NAME = {http://svcs.paypal.com/mobile/adapter/types/pt}GMAdapter
>   03-13 21:24:31.097 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/Server API: Resonse Header: X-PAYPAL-MESSAGE-PROTOCOL = SOAP11
>   03-13 21:24:31.097 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/Server API: Resonse Header: X-PAYPAL-OPERATION-NAME = DeviceInterrogation
>   03-13 21:24:31.097 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/Server API: Resonse Header: X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT = XML
>   03-13 21:24:31.097 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/Server API: Resonse Header: Content-Type = text/xml;charset=UTF-8
>   03-13 21:24:31.097 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/Server API: Resonse Header: Vary = Accept-Encoding
>   03-13 21:24:31.097 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/Server API: Resonse Header: Keep-Alive = timeout=5, max=100
>   03-13 21:24:31.097 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/Server API: Resonse Header: Connection = Keep-Alive
>   03-13 21:24:31.097 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/Server API: Resonse Header: Transfer-Encoding = chunked
>   03-13 21:24:31.097 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/NetworkHandler: postXML setup to read reponse
>   03-13 21:24:31.097 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/NetworkHandler: postXML do read response
>   03-13 21:24:31.097 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo I/System.out: Thread-46238 calls detatch()
>   03-13 21:24:31.097 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/Server API: Response 2016-03-13T18:24:30.475-07: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
>   03-13 21:24:31.097 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/MPL: end makeDeviceInterrogationRequest Post
>   03-13 21:24:31.097 28062-28090/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/MPL: end CHECK_AUTH ok

After that displays, clicking the button only displays this message again:

> 03-13 21:25:35.027 28062-28062/org.kevinbright.android.paypaldemo D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN

and nothing else.

Here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity   {


    final static public int PAYPAL_BUTTON_ID = 10001;
    private static final int REQUEST_PAYPAL_CHECKOUT = 2;
    private double _theSubtotal;
    private double _taxAmount;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initLibrary();
        showPayPalButton();


    }

    private void showPayPalButton() {

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        params.bottomMargin = 10;

        // Generate the PayPal checkout button and save it for later use
        PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();
        CheckoutButton launchPayPalButton = pp.getCheckoutButton(this, PayPal.BUTTON_194x37, CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);

        // Add the listener to the layout
        launchPayPalButton.setLayoutParams(params);
        launchPayPalButton.setId(PAYPAL_BUTTON_ID);
        ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout01)).
                addView(launchPayPalButton);
        ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout01))
                .setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        // The OnClick listener for the checkout button
        launchPayPalButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                payPalButtonClick(arg0);
            }
        });
    }

    public void payPalButtonClick(View arg0) {
        PayPalPayment newPayment = new PayPalPayment();
        newPayment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal(_theSubtotal));
        newPayment.setCurrencyType("USD");
        newPayment.setRecipient("my@email.com");
        newPayment.setMerchantName("My Company");
        Intent checkoutIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(newPayment, MainActivity.this);
        startActivityForResult(checkoutIntent, REQUEST_PAYPAL_CHECKOUT);
    }

    public void initLibrary() {
        PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();

        if (pp == null) {  // Test to see if the library is already initialized

            // This main initialization call takes your Context, AppID, and target server
            pp = PayPal.initWithAppID(this, "APP-80W284485P519543T", PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);

            // Required settings:

            // Set the language for the library
            pp.setLanguage("en_US");

            // Some Optional settings:

            // Sets who pays any transaction fees. Possible values are:
            // FEEPAYER_SENDER, FEEPAYER_PRIMARYRECEIVER, FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER, and FEEPAYER_SECONDARYONLY
            pp.setFeesPayer(PayPal.FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER);

            // true = transaction requires shipping
            pp.setShippingEnabled(true);

        }

    }

}
```

I posted a similar question here:

[onClick not doing anything... "ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931336/onclick-not-doing-anything-viewpostimeinputstage-action-down)

The suggestions were: (1) wrap a parent layout around my current parent layout, and (2) implement an onClickListener via an annyomous inner class (as opposed to implementing it on the entire activity).

I did both of those things and revised the code, as shown above.  I've also reviewed the other questions and answers posted here on this issue, but nothing seems to work, and I can't figure out why it's not working.